# Why is my textarea wider than the page?

Tags: css, xhtml

I wrote an XHTML 1.0 Transitional page (validated using the W3C's validator), containing a `table` with a `textarea` in it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea rows="" cols="">
            </textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And, in an external stylesheet, I wrote code for the `table` and `textarea`:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

But, for some reason, the padding of the `textarea` affects its width, and causes the `textarea` to exceed the width of the page, resulting in unwanted overflow.

Is there some way I can apply padding to the `textarea` without it affecting its width?

Comment: "for some reason, the padding of the textarea affects its width" - yup. That's how CSS works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for some reason, the padding of the textarea affects its width

Yup, that's how CSS works. `width` refers to the width of the element's content area. Padding, borders and margin are treated separately by default.

See e.g. http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html

> Is there some way I can apply padding to the textarea without it affecting the TextArea's width?

The CSS `box-sizing:border-box` rule does what you want:

```
textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

It tells the browser to treat `width` as referring to the combined width of the content, padding and border areas of the element. So, the width of the `<textarea>`'s content area will be set to 100% of the parent element, minus the 40 pixels of horizontal padding.

Note, however, that `border-box` is not supported in IE 7 or earlier.

Comment: Works perfectly now, much thanks. I had no knowledge at all of this property or its influence. I was even able to give the table padding without its contents overflowing.

Comment: @LogicalAngel: yeah, it's very very handy. (In Quirks Mode, IE 7 and earlier treated width in the `box-sizing:border-box;` way by default.) You're most welcome - upvotes (click the arrow above the "0" in the top left corner of my answer) and acceptances (click the tick) are gratefully accepted too. Welcome to Stack Overflow!